# How to delete a specific row in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I want to delete 9 rows with duplicated IDs, got the index for them then tried delete but the length after deletion shows that 714 rows got deleted. Is the pandas index not unique? How can I do this correctly

I search the pandas dataframe and identified the rows I wanted to delete. Wrote down the IDs then attempted deletion but something went wrong it seems.
I suspect the pandas index is not unique and more than intended row got deleted.
How can I create a unique index or how to use the index correctly?

```
len(CrimeClean) #result 690130

CrimeCleanV1 = CrimeClean.drop([5650, 3725, 6373, 2469, 7751, 7058, 3859, 3640, 3141])
#Validation, row 7751 should not appear
CrimeCleanV1[CrimeCleanV1.Crime_ID == "56882eb6d444d5677ac90c06a0582fe70fe1fd932fd5bd902a5aa4a2aa363bf3"]

#Only one row instead of two appeared as intended

len(CrimeCleanV1) #result 689416
```

[image: Code]
[image: Code Cont.]

Comment: have you already thought about using `drop_duplicates`? Are 5650 labels from the index, or are they row numbers?

Comment: The rows I am trying to delete only have Duplicate IDs but they are not completely the same so drop_duplicates won't delete them. 5650 and the rest of the numbers I got from the search in the first pic on the far left side (Still not sure if they are index or not) @jottbe

Comment: In that case they are index labels. It should work then. It could just be, that your index is not unique for some reason (e.g. after concatenation of two dataframes). What happens if you do `CrimeClean.loc[[5650...`? Do you get only as many rows as you have ids or more?

Comment: I tried CrimeClean.loc[5650] and it gave me 89 different rows! also it might be useful but the dataframe is originaly 103 different csv files imported at once

Comment: I ran CrimeClean = CrimeClean.reset_index(drop=True) and redid search 
Edited the indexes then deleted and it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: does the id have any significance? if not you should reindex it. For concatenating your dataframes, you could check out option `ignore_index=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
CrimeCleanV1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Then

```
CrimeCleanV1[~CrimeCleanV1.index.isin([List with your row numbers where now they are indexes])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in your comment: *they are not completely the same*.
So I assume that the criterion to mark a row as duplicate is a **list**
of columns, which should be unique.

So you can drop duplicates, passing *subset* parameter, with just
this list of columns.

Another point to decide is which duplicated rows are actually to be
deleted (*keep* parameter) - leave **first** occurrence / leave
**last** occurrence / **drop all**.

Another important test concerning your data is to run:

```
CrimeClean[CrimeClean.index in [...]]
```

substituting as *[...]* the same list as you used in *CrimeClean.drop*.

Then you will see, how many rows exist with the passed id values.